# How can I create a list for each iteration of a for-loop?

Tags: python, list, for-loop

I'm setting up an algorithm and I do not achieve to create a list for each loop index.

I don't know how can I change the names of lists during the for-loop.

```py
for i in range(10):
   list = list.append(1 + i)
```

In order to get:

```py
list0 = [1]
list1 = [2]
list2 = [3]
and so on.
```

My objective is to call these lists on another function, is there a way to name these lists with the list index?

I don't have find any subject which describe my issue. Maybe I don't clearly explain my problem.

Comment: Why not use nested lists (2d array)?

Comment: @Shijith this line create only one list, right?

Comment: @Bandoleras, yes it will create only one list

Comment: do not call your variable after built ins - you shadow them, i.e. never use `list,min,max,set,dict,range` etc. as variable name

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It isn't efficient to create those variables, instead a dictionary would come in handy:

```
d = {}
for i in range(10):
   d['list%s' % i] = [i + 1]
```

It actually could be done with:

```
d = {'list%s' % i: [i + 1] for i in range(10)}
```

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question, you can do this but I think that it is not a best practice for your issue:

```
for i in range(10):
   locals()['list{}'.format(i)] = [1 + i]
```

You can see that this code created 10 variables :

```
>>>print(list0)
[1]
>>>print(list9)
[10]
```

I'd prefer using a dict as in @U9-Forward answer

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing that assign them all to a reference in another list e.g.

```
Lst [0] = [1]
Lst [1] = [2]
```

This is done with:

```
Lst=[]
for i in range(10):
    Lst.append(i+1)
```

Comment: `TypeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object is not subscriptable`

Comment: I msitakingly put [] in the loop, should work now, tested it

Comment: this will create a list of integers - same as `Lst = list(range(10))` - probably not what the OP wanted

Comment: Yes it will, but the benefit of this is you can use this to append nested lists e.g. Lst.append([i,i+1]) which i believe OP was after